# Can we make version tags a must for every question?

Tags: feature-request

There are many questions where users dont mention their Ubuntu version and ppl then ask them to add the version of Ubuntu they are using to their question so question could be answered accordingly. Why dont we make at least one version tag a must for any new question? Similar to how a question on meta must have at least one of feature-request, bug, support or discussion tag added.

I understand that there are questions which dont require version info and can be answered without it but having version info for even those questions wont harm.

Answer (score 10):

## No

There are questions that are version agnostic, where it could apply to multiple versions. Forcing version tags is a bad idea as versions then become meta tags. Currently, tagging a post with a version should only happen when that post is directly related to that release in some way. If you have problems with Apache and PHP don't tag [11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/11.10) because it's not really [11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/11.10) specific. It's [apache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/apache) and [php](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php).

Comment: I've submitted descriptions to the version tags to make this more clear.

Answer (score -5):

I wish that we would.

No matter the question, the user is asking to resolve something on *their* installation of a supported/unsupported version.

Given how much time is spent in the already over-stuffed review queues, requiring a supported version tag when creating a question could go a long way to reducing the number of questions reviewed.