# Which questions should get the release tag "14.04"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm trying to understand which questions should get the tag **"14.04"**.

I had rejected two sugested edits, both adding only the tag to:

[How do I install MP3 codecs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528527/how-do-i-install-mp3-codecs)
[newest kernel not loading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528544/newest-kernel-not-loading)

But on other questions, I accepted adding the tag, without being able to say why it should be there - or why not.

These are examples **with** the tag where I think the tag does not apply:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/528488/low-resolution-after-upgrading-from-13-10-to-14-04
[Mouse stutters, slows down, requires multiple clicks, sometimes freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528568/mouse-stutters-slows-down-requires-multiple-clicks-sometimes-freezes)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/528565/problem-with-ati-graphics-card

To remove the tag, or reject an edit adding it, I want to be able to say **why!**

Of course there are questions that are directly related to a release, they deserve the tag.

At the other end of the spectrum, there are other questions that are clearly not specific to the release, even if they use "14.04" in the text.

**But where is the separation?**

Is it expected to apply very broad, or strict?

*The tag wiki says:*

> The current LTS (Long Term Support) release of Ubuntu, code-named "Trusty Tahr".  Released on 17th April, 2014. Only use this tag if your question is version-specific.

How is **"version-specific"** meant?
As in:

> Foo broke when installing 14.04.

Or more like:

> I was using Bar in the version from 14.04 for...

Comment: Related: [Can we make version tags a must for every question?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2213), [When should we use the versions tags?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1521), [Don't mix version specific tags with stuff that isn't version specific!](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8875), most of them will say: only if it's really version specific. "Version specific" meaning: you can't reproduce in any other version of Ubuntu, which is almost all. Only valid version specific question which the tag is correctly applied I've ever seen is [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/528116/169736)

Comment: BTW, both your examples are not when its meant to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version tags are for when the Ubuntu version (or that era) is relevant to the problem.

As Braiam and I display on a monthly basis, there's furious and fundamental disagreement  over what "relevant" means. Actually, we'll fight over the definition of every word in the above statement. I semi-jokingly [reduced](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8874/449) their whole argument into [a flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLIAk.png).

I'll stake my opinion where people can vote on it and I will *suggest* adding, allowing somebody to add, or reject the removal of a version tag when:

- The question is comparing a problem with other versions or calling out a difference in the way things used to work, requesting detail for something in a new version. I'd cite [one of my own questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/445637/449) as an example of that.
- When hardware is involved. Ubuntu versions broadly map to Kernel versions and snapshots of the X stack. Being able to search for `[12.04] <wifi chipset>` is great if you're having problems. People have made the argument for searching for `12.04 <wifi chipset>` but this would include meaningless mentions like "It was working in 12.04 but broke since my upgrade to 14.04".

That's about it. There's obviously an amount of technical understanding here that OPs won't always understand or appreciate but if you understand the problem enough (as you probably do), you should be able to make these judgements.

Questions that fit the "I was using Bar in the version from 14.04" usually won't need a version tag but again, if it's something super-new to that version or the software is something that's known to get significant updates to it every release (eg Unity, Kernel, X, etc), that might warrant a version tag.

---

On a slightly different tack, most of your examples need *significant* editing but that's been completely ignored during the retag. Don't be afraid to reject things just for being lazy. If you're going to open up the edit screen, you might as well try and fix the post too.

That's more important than tagging anyway.

Comment: Did you notice they took too-minor away? Yeah, some idea that we should always 'improve' the too minor edits...